# Any help to undefined parameter when I was going to pass the map index to my component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, arrow-functions

As the question describes, I am going to show the code below.

```
[An array].map((item, index) => {
    return <TreeItem key={index} id_index={index} ...other props are no problem />
})
```

```
function TreeItem(props) {
    ...
    console.log(props.id_index)
    ...
}
```

Somehow in my TreeItem function I cannot get the index from props.id_index instead always `undefined`.

Additional info:
I am having two function based components, one is about to load tree structure of TreeItem components, the TreeItem component can has its own TreeItem as well, so my idea is to keep the index of each TreeItem for later operations, I am confusing why TreeItem in map loop can take all props even function prop but the index is undefined.

Many thanks for anyone can help and let me know why this weird problem happen, it is killing me..

Comment: What is the value of the index in the map function?

Comment: Show your actual code, this seems to be fine and should work

Answer (score 0):

By adding `id_index` prop like `id_index="0"` to parent node of TreeItem, it works.
I think it is due to my TreeItem function take all the paramerters include `id_index` because I did not pass prop value to parent node, then caused the inside map loop problem, still confusing why inside map need passing prop to parent component, will post details if I find the reason or someone can answer it completely.

```
<TreeItem nodeId="1" labelText="A" labelIcon={Label} id="1" cb={refresh} id_index="0" parentId="1">
  {
     mapper["1"].map((item, index) => {
          return <StyledTreeItem key={index} nodeId={item.id} labelText={item.text} labelIcon={Label} id={item.id} cb={refresh} id_index={index} parentId="1" />
     })
  }  
</TreeItem>
```